# The argument of a finite Euler product at a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-product

With $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number, we know that:

$$\arg\left(\zeta(s)\right)=\arg\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_n^s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arg\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_n^s}}\right)\qquad \Re(s) > 1$$

Now define the finite series:

$$f(s,N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \arg\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_n^s}}\right) \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}$$

and plot it for values at and near a non-trivial zero ($\rho$) of $\zeta(s)$ for subsequent $N$. This gives for instance:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For $N \rightarrow \infty$ these oscillating series show a reducing frequency and increasing amplitude ('spiral waves'). Oscillating series do neither converge or diverge. however it seems that only when $s=\rho$ (middle graph) the oscillation occurs along a horizontal line (the same pattern emerges for all $\rho$s I tested).

Is there any possible way of calculating the location of such a line?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler product diverges for $\Re(s) < 1$, you need to replace it by the regularized version (valid for $\Re(s)\in (1/2,1)$ **assuming the RH is true**)

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} -\sum_{p \le x} \log(1-p^{-s}) - pv\int_0^x \frac{t^{-s}}{\log t}dt + \frac{\log(s-1)}{s}$$

If there are infinitely many zeros of real part $\ge \Re(s) $ then there is no regularized version at $s$.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that the Euler product doesn't converge for $\Re(s) < 1$, hence my attempt with the finite product to see wether there was anything interesting going on around the $\rho$s. Is there any reason why these finite series oscillate around a horizontal line only at $\rho$s?

Comment: It oscillates everywhere but the amplitude depends on how close the zero/pole is, that's the explicit formula.